# Wordpress Search results separate main posts from Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, search

I have a custom post type named 'Artists'.
My current search results are pulling this post type along with my standard posts in one grouping. 
I am having trouble separating the two posts types in my results.

Instead of...

- Blog Post
- Blog Post
- Artist Post
- Blog Post
- Artist Post

I'd like....

BLOG POSTS:

- Blog Post
- Blog Post
- Blog Post

ARTIST POSTS:

- Artist Post
- Artist Post

Is that possible? I am not sure if I can solve this with one loop/query or it would be faster to use two queries?

Current code is here...

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php the_date(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Any help appreciated. I realize there are some similar questions on this already, but most have been unhelpful for this particular situation.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the order of the wp_query object

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'type'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

OP is to lazy to read the Docs so here i provide an example:

```
$args = array('order' => 'type');
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
 //
}
```

EDIT:
Here another possible solution if you want to avoid a new Instance of wp-query and use the global Object:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','my_sort_custom',10,2);
function my_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_search()) 
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type ASC"

    return  $orderby;
}
```